# Change Class or CSS "display" property of a DIV and show it smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hidden div and I need to to show it smoothly with different CSS styles, all styles may be changed easily except the "display". But this property is crucial, because when it start appearing, it will move other elements on the page differently. It will depends on the "display" property of the appearing element. Either next element will move right, or down.

I have 2 buttons - (show div as block) and (show div as inline block) and it should work, but it is not.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/pqrdS/151/)

Here is another [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/pqrdS/154/), showing how to change the display property on visible div. I need to change it while the div is hidden and then show it with new display property smoothly with simple ".toggle(500);".

```js
$("#f").hide();

$(".toggle_h").bind("click", function(){    
    $("#f").hide();
})

$(".toggle_b").bind("click", function(){    
    $("#f")    
    .removeClass('i')
    .addClass('b')
    .toggle(500);
    return false;
})

$(".toggle_i").bind("click", function(){    
    $("#f")    
    .removeClass('b')
    .addClass('i')
    .toggle(500);
    return false;
})
```

```css
.b{
    display:block;
    background:red;
}

.i{
    display:inline-block;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">block1 block</div>
<div id='f' >block2 flexible</div> 
<div class="i">block3 inline</div> 
<br>
<a href="#" class="toggle_b">show as block</a><br>
<a href="#" class="toggle_i">show as inline</a><br>
<a href="#" class="toggle_h">hide</a><br>
```

Comment: From a very quick experiment it looks like when jquery hides and element it remembers the previous `disaplay` value and restores that value as an inline style. I used Firebug for Firefox to inspect the element as it was changed.

Comment: I Agree, but as far as there is no solution I put my own "it is impossible" answer. You can "+1" it if you agree with the statement.

Comment: You want the element to smoothly transition from `display: block` to `display: inline`?

Comment: No, I need to change the "display" property while the element is hidden and then show it smoothly. It must start appearing and  moving other elements on the page differently, depending on the "display" property of the appearing element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is impossible.

But there is a way to bypass this bug.
Just wrap the content of the div into another div and toggle the content wrapper, while your original div will stay visible because on the visible div you can change the display option.

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pqrdS/155/)

```js
$(".toggle_b").bind("click", function(){    
    $("#w").hide();
     $("#f")        
      .removeClass('i')
      .addClass('b')
     $("#w").toggle(500);
})

$(".toggle_i").bind("click", function(){
    $("#w").hide();
    $("#f")    
    .removeClass('b')
    .addClass('i');
    $("#w").toggle(500);
})
```

```css
.b{
    display:block;
    background:red;
}

.i{
    display:inline-block;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="b">block1 block</div>
<div id='f'> <div id='w' > block2 flexible</div> </div> 
<div class="i">block3 inline</div> 
<br>
<a href="#" class="toggle_b">show as block</a><br>
<a href="#" class="toggle_i">show as inline</a><br>
```

The alternative way I found would be changing not "display", but another CSS property to achieve similar effect, use "float: left;".

BUT floated elements can't have vertical-alignment inside them.

Answer (score -1):

With no parameters, `$("#f").hide();` will hide the element immediately with no animation. If you want to animate it, add a duration parameter, e.g.

```
$(".toggle_h").bind("click", function(){    
    $("#f").hide(500);
})
```

Comment: as I pointed in my question - "I need to to SHOW div smoothly" i don't need to hide it smoothly. Sorry, your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: The point was to show the DIV differently, you probably noticed that if you press "show as inline" the div appears in blue colour, this colour comes from the class ".i", and this class should also give the div a property "display:inline-block;". But it is not working, the "display" property of appearing div is always "display:block;".

Answer (score -1):

The `display` property cannot be transitioned. Using jQuery's `show` and `hide` methods are essentially the same as just saying `display: block` and `display: none` in CSS, which, as I just mentioned, can't be transitioned. However, a property like `opacity` or `width` CAN be transitioned with CSS. You'd want to toggle a class instead of using `.show` and `.hide` though, and let CSS do the transitioning.

If you're looking to simply fade in and out using jQuery, you could replace your `.hide` method with `.fadeOut`.

*Note: I hope this is what you were referring to :)*

Comment: I don't need a transition of the "display" property. This is how you can change display property on visible div, take a look: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynewbox/pqrdS/154/). I need to change it while the div is hidden and then show it with new display property smoothly with simple ".toggle(500);".

Comment: The point was to show the DIV differently, you probably noticed that if you press "show as inline" the div appears in blue colour, this colour comes from the class ".i", and this class should also give the div a property "display:inline-block;". But it is not working, the "display" property of appearing div is always "display:block;".